# How can i separate textviews to affect only one textview?

Tags: java, android

I am using onTouchEvent method to scale textview, but i am getting trouble when i have two textviews and i only want to resize the first one and not the second one. I mean, i want to scale both separately. What should i do?

**Method**

```
 @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getPointerCount() == 2) {
            int action = event.getAction();
            int pureaction = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
            if (pureaction == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN) {
                mBaseDist = getDistance(event);
                mBaseRatio = mRatio;
            } else {
                float delta = (getDistance(event) - mBaseDist) / STEP;
                float multi = (float)Math.pow(2, delta);
                mRatio = Math.min(1024.0f, Math.max(0.1f, mBaseRatio * multi));
                //Definir aquí el tamaño del texto
                textView1.setTextSize(mRatio+13);
                textView2.setTextSize(mRatio+13);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: You could test over which TextView the touch event is and scale only this one.

Comment: You are resizing both the `TextViews`

Comment: just remove `textView2.setTextSize(mRatio+13); `

Comment: But if i remove textview2 i won't be able to resize this one, then, with both textviews inside the method, how can i resize each one separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
View.OnTouchListener onTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
@Override
 public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    if (event.getPointerCount() == 2) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        int pureaction = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
        if (pureaction == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN) {
            mBaseDist = getDistance(event);
            mBaseRatio = mRatio;
        } else {
            float delta = (getDistance(event) - mBaseDist) / STEP;
            float multi = (float)Math.pow(2, delta);
            mRatio = Math.min(1024.0f, Math.max(0.1f, mBaseRatio * multi));
           ((TextView)view).setTextSize(mRatio+13);
            //Definir aquí el tamaño del texto
            //textView1.setTextSize(mRatio+13);
            //textView2.setTextSize(mRatio+13);
        }
    }
    return true;
});
textView1.setOnTouchListener(onTouchListener );
textView2.setOnTouchListener(onTouchListener );
```

It will scale both Textview separately.

Comment: Thaks for your answer. It's not letting me to put ");"     neither `textView1.setOnTouchListener(onTouchListener );` it says, cannot resolve setOntouchListener. So, have you set this method in or out onCreate?

Comment: The above method would go outside of your onCreate method

Comment: I was already using onTouch method and i had declared View.OntouchListener and my onTouch method was already filled with movement code so, i did this modification of  @Himesh Goswami answer at the end of method and everything is working fine. 
`View onTouchListener = findViewById(R.id.textview_top);
        View onTouchListener1 = findViewById(R.id.textview_bottom);
        onTouchListener.setOnTouchListener(this);
        onTouchListener1.setOnTouchListener(this);
        return true;`  
Thank you!! i will validate the answer